# LockBox TwoFish string encryption and decryption

Tags: cryptography, delphi

I'm using TurboPower LockBox for the first time, and using the TwoFish algorithm to first encrypt a password, and later retrieve the password by decrypting the generated hash.

I would like to know if the approach that I'm using is good, and if there are any pitfalls to avoid. Its a simple use case for my application to store and later retrieve a mail server password.

This is the code I'm using:

```
// Steve Faleiro 2016-03-06
uses uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary, uTPLb_Codec;

function TwoFish_ENC(const AString: String): String;
var
  CryptoLib: TCryptographicLibrary;
  Codec: TCodec;
  encryptedStr: String;
begin
  CryptoLib := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  try
    Codec.CryptoLibrary := CryptoLib;
    Codec.StreamCipherId := 'native.StreamToBlock';
    Codec.BlockCipherId := 'native.Twofish';
    Codec.ChainModeId := 'native.CBC';

    Codec.Reset;
    Codec.Password := '56410AD2-9DD6-4B8C-9D2F-5DE7A7F7085E';
    Codec.EncryptString(AString, encryptedStr, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    CryptoLib.Free;
    Codec.Free;
  end;

  Result := encryptedStr;
end;

function TwoFish_DEC(const AString: String): String;
var
  CryptoLib: TCryptographicLibrary;
  Codec: TCodec;
  decryptedStr: String;
begin
  CryptoLib := TCryptographicLibrary.Create(nil);
  Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
  try
    Codec.CryptoLibrary := CryptoLib;
    Codec.StreamCipherId := 'native.StreamToBlock';
    Codec.BlockCipherId := 'native.Twofish';
    Codec.ChainModeId := 'native.CBC';

    Codec.Reset;
    Codec.Password := '56410AD2-9DD6-4B8C-9D2F-5DE7A7F7085E';
    Codec.DecryptString(decryptedStr, AString, TEncoding.UTF8);
  finally
    CryptoLib.Free;
    Codec.Free;
  end;

  Result := decryptedStr;
end;
```

Is it good enough? If not, is there any way to improve it?

Comment: `Is it good enough?` What's your [threat model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model)?

Comment: Ordinary home-based business. Nothing much.

Comment: I would use the newer versions of LockBox. There are at least two people I know of who are working on this. The TurboPower one is quite old.